# Update Div Class Based on Inputs

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with 2 text inputs and 1 textarea:

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</form>
```

And a div element that has a background image applied:

```
<div class="img-holder"></div>
```

What I would like to accomplish is the following:

As a user completes the form I would like to add a class to the img-holder div based on how many fields have been completed.

In other words, if the user completed 3 fields add the class="3", if 2 add the class="2", and if 1 add the class="1". Also if they clear any of the inputs the class would update accordingly.

Using jQuery how can I monitor each input and update the class based on how many fields are completed?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CthulhuDen/gKcKq/

```
$(function() {
    $("form").children().change(function() {
        var cnt = 0;
        $("form").children().each(function() {
            if ($(this).val()) cnt++;
        });
        $("form").removeClass("class1 class2 class3").addClass("class" + cnt)
    });
});
```

Form class changes based on the number of fields filled.

Of course you will have to change selector in the last line for your div.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').change(function() {
    var answers = 0;
    var ansData = $('form').serializeArray();
    var $vals = ansData.value;
    $vals.each(function() {
        if ($(this) != '') answers++;
    });
    $('.img-holder').addClass(answers);
});
```

Comment: OP might like to know how to bind this handler to an event.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form action="#" id="a_form">
    <input type="text" id="first_input"/>
    <input type="text" id="second_input"/>
    <textarea name="" id="third_input" cols="30" rows="10" ></textarea>
</form>
<div class="img-holder"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function () {
   var a = $('#first_input').val() ? 0 : 1;
   var b = $('#second_input').val() ? 0 : 1;
   var c = $('#third_input').val() ? 0 : 1;


   var result = a+b+c;
   result = result != 0 ? result : "";
   $('.img-holder').removeClass("1 2 3").addClass(result);
});
```

You should only use this solution if the page doesn't have any other inputs... Because it will watch any keypress on the entire page to call this 'validation'